# Density of closed orbits on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

It is well-known that the set of closed geodesics on a closed hyperbolic surface is dense.

My questions:

1. If this property still holds on finite-area hyperbolic surfaces, infinite-area hyperbolic surfaces or even orbifolds? Counter-examples?
2. If there is a general result for all cases under some conditions?

Comment: This is related to the limit set of a Fuchsian group uniformising the surface. So the general answer (for a complete hyperbolic surface) is that closed geodesic are dense if and only if the surface has no end isometric to a quotient of a half-plane by an hyperbolic element. (In particular the answer is always positive for finite-volume oribifolds).

Comment: Thanks, Jean Raimbault, do you know any reference for this fact?

Comment: Density follows immediately from one of the equivalent characterisations of the limit set (that it is the closure of the set of ends of hyperbolic elemnts of the group). You can find information about the limit in most books on hyperbolic geometry, for example Beardon's of Ratcliffes's, which shluld be sufficient to write a detailed proof.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, so can I say that: the set of end points of geodesics $\{(\gamma^{+},\gamma^{-})|\gamma \in \Gamma\}$ is dense in $\Lambda(\Gamma)\times \Lambda(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is a non-elementary (discrete condition is not necessary) subgroup of orientation-preserving isometry over $\mathbb{H}$?

Comment: Yes, this is in Beardon's book. you should write down the solution as an answer once you've figured it out so the question does not remain without one.